# SharePoint List Export to Excel All Columns!

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, excel, export

As you may know SharePoint's default export to excel only exports the columns of that current view to excel. Is there anyway to export all columns, without adding all columns to that current view.

Comment: The export to Excel feature will export only those fields which are added in current view. What is your purpose to export SharePoint list to Excel?

Comment: For reporting purposes. Some users need to get the Excel report of the Employee List with all data (columns). I cannot put all those columns to the current view, because there is a lot of column. Putting them to the current view; page is not displayin well because of the width of all columns.

Comment: I have not tried but ,It is possible to export list within all fields programatically.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible, but today I just did an Export to Excel from a view of a list and the result contains nineteen additional columns that are not displayed in the view. These 19 columns are found to the right of the "Item Type" and "Path" columns in the spreadsheet.  I only have Read access to the list, so I don't know how it was accomplished, but I couldn't find any clues in DOM Explorer (my first guess was some JS/CSS hiding the columns - nope).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you make another personal view with all columns?

Comment: if there is no alternative way, that will be, i think, the only solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another view (Export to excel) from create view and add all the columns to the view for export.